# Why do we need to run a local server for running a pure html/css/js app?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, httpserver

Why can't we just run the web app by running/opening the `index.html`?

Why does the `file:///C:/[...address]/index.html` not loading the `css/js` correctly like `http://localhost:3000/`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few notes that we should consider:

### 1- Diffrent Protocols

I should mention that there are two protocols:

1. [File protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767731(v%3Dvs.85)) which is prefixed by `file:///`
2. [HTTP(network)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767734(v%3Dvs.85)) protocol which is prefixed by `http://`

So they are two different protocols therefore the browsers treated them differently.

### 2- Different path resolver

Root relative links e.g. `src="/js/modal.js"` are available when using a server to run our app(to simply run the app on HTTP protocol)

##### server based:

`<a href="home.html">Home</a>`   ->  `http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html`

`<a href="/home.html">Home</a>`   -> `http://127.0.0.1:5500/home.html`

##### file based:

`<a href="home.html">Home</a>`   ->  `file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/home.html`

`<a href="/home.html">Home</a>`   -> `file:///C:/home.html`

#### 3- Cookies and local storage

Based on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

> `localStorage` data **is specific to the protocol of the document**. In particular, for a site loaded over HTTP (e.g., `http://example.com`), `localStorage` returns a different object than `localStorage` for the corresponding site loaded over HTTPS (e.g., `https://example.com`).
>
> For documents loaded from `file:` URLs (that is, files opened in the browser directly from the user’s local filesystem, rather than being served from a web server) the requirements for `localStorage` behavior are undefined and may vary among different browsers.
>
> In all current browsers, `localStorage` seems to return a different object for each `file:` URL. In other words, each `file:` URL seems to have its own unique local-storage area. But there are no guarantees about that behavior, so you shouldn’t rely on it because, as mentioned above, the requirements for `file:` URLs remain undefined. So it’s possible that browsers may change their `file:` URL handling for `localStorage` at any time. In fact some browsers *have* changed their handling for it over time.

And Based on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), `Cookies` are small blocks of data created by a web server while a user is browsing a website, So, it is strictly an HTTP mechanism which will be accessible when we use a web server to run our web app.

#### 4- CORS

Based on [Cross origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) You can not send `ajax` request on `file`.

#### finally

There are quite a few features that I haven't listed here(e.g. service worker, and security features) That can't be used with `file` type.